# Flex + Runtime + httpFaultHandler

Tags: apache-flex, runtime

I'm creating a graph and loading images.

When I try to run the program using the builder, it works fine, but minute I export it and try to run it, I get an httpFaultHandler issue.

I've tried to give the absolute path, logical path, but no success.

My sequence of creation of object are:

```
    1. In Application, i've set the creationPolicy="all"
    1a. On creationComplete I'm loading populateGraph function.
    2. Creating an Panel
    3. Creating a VBox
    4. Creating a SpringGraph
    4a. on Initialization of SpringGraph I'm populating my XML using HTTPService
```

When I print the value of the XML during runtime, its shows blank :(.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried building the `swf` with `-use-network`?

Also, you say that the value of the XML is blank at runtime… Is this before or after the fault? Or is that a separate issue?

Comment: David, I haven't tried building the swf using that option. The value of XML on runtime is blank before the fault.

Comment: On my 1st comment a correction, the XML content is blank since I get a httpFault, I printed the AsyncToken value and it was correct i.e. its a Token

var temp: AsyncToken = httpService.send();
Alert.show("temp="+temp.message);

But it goes to faultHandler